# NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW for Product Reviews Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.4, google

I haven't been able to work out how to do a noindex, nofollow of my product reviews in magento 2.3.4

I have a robot.txt setup with custom disallows including /review
But I'm still seeing it come up in my google search console.

Could someone help point me in the right direction.